# How to come back to previous rootview of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two layouts **layout1** and **layout2**.

Initially in onCreateView of my fragment I am using layout1 like this:

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);

            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setViewLayout(R.layout.layout2);
            }
        });


            return rootView;
    }
```

After that onclick button I am changing **rootView** from **layout1** two **layout2** and its working fine:

This is how I am changing:

```
private void setViewLayout(int id){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(id, null);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
        viewGroup.removeAllViews();
        viewGroup.addView(rootView);
    }
```

To access fields of **layout2** I created one class and instantiate it on onClick event of button:

Now I want to go back **layout1** from **layout2** I did same and view is changing but fields are not working like onClick button of layout1 is not responding now.

PS: I don't want to start fragment again, I just want my previous layout1 instead of new one.

How I can go back so that I can use my previous states of **layout1**?

Answer (score 1):

the better approach here is to use two separate fragment for each layout and on Click replace the current fragment with second one.

you won't be able to recover your previous layout as you have removed that from the rootview

secondly you are not saving fragment state

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it is done. You need to add fragment in a backstack to maintain the state. Check [implement back navigation for fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments) from android developer site. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Replace Fragment. Not setViewLayout(R.layout.layout2)

Comment: you can't setViewLayout on onClickListener. You just startActivity or Replace Fragment.